# How to solve problematic cpu load due to encryption when using SFTP on a VM

Tags: ssh, sftp, encryption, cpu-usage

my company is trying offer a sftp service for a big amount of customers.
The serving machine will be on a VM and tests have shown that, with an increasing amount of simultaneous users, the cpu becomes heavily utilized solely by doing the connection encryption.

Is there a known way to tackle this problem. Maybe with something like externalizing the encyrption operations on actual hardware.

I'd love to hear your suggestions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: use ftps which is lighter but does not offer the exact same capabilities.

Comment: What virtualization? Basically I would assume you have an offload problem ersulting in the VM doing the cryptographic processing.

Comment: we are using VMWare vCenter

Comment: Kiwy: I don’t see why using FTPS (FTP with TLS) would be “lighter.” TLS uses similar mechanisms to encrypt bulk data with well-known ciphers like AES, 3DES, etc., and will have similar performance characteristics (implementation differences aside).

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the SSH encryption and MAC algorithms for a better security/performance tradeoff? What SSH server are you using? Which algorithms are you currently offering? Which ones are actually being negotiated by the clients?

Comment: Have you done the same tests without encryption, to rule out a different problem?  How are you determining it's the encryption doing it, and not for example a slow disk.